# Maintaining both sides of self-referential many-to-many relationship in Grails domain object

Tags: grails, groovy, many-to-many, grails-orm

I'm having some problems getting a many-to-many relationship working in grails.  Is there anything obviously wrong with the following:

```
class Person {
    static hasMany = [friends: Person]
    static mappedBy = [friends: 'friends']

    String name
    List friends = []

    String toString() {
        return this.name
    }
}

class BootStrap {
     def init = { servletContext ->
        Person bob = new Person(name: 'bob').save()
        Person jaq = new Person(name: 'jaq').save()
        jaq.friends << bob

        println "Bob's friends: ${bob.friends}"
        println "Jaq's friends: ${jaq.friends}"
     }
}
```

I'd expect Bob to be friends with Jaq and vice-versa, but I get the following output at startup:

```
Running Grails application..
Bob's friends: []
Jaq's friends: [Bob]
```

(I'm using Grails 1.2.0)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
class Person {
    static hasMany   = [ friends: Person ]
    static mappedBy  = [ friends: 'friends' ]
    String name

    String toString() {
        name
    }
}
```

and then in the BootStrap:

```
class BootStrap {
     def init = { servletContext ->
        Person bob = new Person(name: 'bob').save()
        Person jaq = new Person(name: 'jaq').save()

        jaq.addToFriends( bob )

        println "Bob's friends: ${bob.friends}"
        println "Jaq's friends: ${jaq.friends}"
     }
}
```

I get the following:

```
Running Grails application..
Bob's friends: [jaq]
Jaq's friends: [bob]
```

Comment: Works a treat, thanks :=)  The significant difference is changing jaq.friends<<bob to jaq.addToFriends(bob).  I'm slightly surprised that they don't do the same thing; it'd be nice to prevent adding of friends on one side of the relationship only.

Comment: Alison - the reason why they don't do the same thing is because << is invoking the leftShift method which simply adds it to the Set. "addToFriends" is a method added to the metaClass of Person that performs the correct underlying hibernate operations for persistence and relationship management.