# Uniary Relationship on Grails GORM

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Based this GORM Domain class:

```
class Component implements Serializable {
    Long id
    String name
    Double total
    Long parentComponentId

    static mapping = {
        ...
    }

    static constraints = {
        ...
        parentComponentId nullable: true
    }
}
```

My questions are:

1. How do we reference a Domain class to itself, on this case
   `parentComponentId` is another instance of `Component`.
2. If that referencing problem in #1 is solved, how can I execute a query similar to this:

   > `select a.*, b.* from COMPONENT a
   >       join COMPONENT b on a.id = b.parentComponentId
   >       group by a.id
   >       having sum(b.total) = a.total`

Comment: Have a bit of a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17653567/how-to-implement-self-referencing-relationships-in-grails. Seems like you should replace the `Long` property with a `Component` one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the `Long parentComponentId` to `Component parentComponent`. You also don't need the `Long id` property, as grails add it for you:

```
class Component implements Serializable {
    String name
    Double total
    Component parentComponent

    static constraints = {
        parentComponent nullable: true
    }
}
```

Then you can access both the parent component and the parent component id:

`assert Component.read(1).parentComponentId == Component.read(1).parentComponent.id`

If you want to have cascade deletes, you'll need to remove the parentComponent property and add:

```
static hasMany = [nestedComponents: Component]
static belongsTo = [parentComponent: Component]
```

I'm assuming you have a `0:N` relationship, if not you'll need to change that. Check [the documentation for defining associations](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#manyToOneAndOneToOne).

As for your second question, sadly you can't use `having` in a criteria yet: https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7880

You can do it with HQL though:

```
Component.executeQuery("""
   select parent from Component parent, Component nested
   where nested.parentComponent = parent
   group by parent
   having parent.total = sum(nested.total)
""".toString())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this for first question.

```
class Component implements Serializable {
    Long id
    String name
    Double total
    static belongsTo = [parentComponentId:Component]
    static mapping = {
        ...
    }

    static constraints = {
        ...
        parentComponentId nullable: true
    }
}
```